# filter an array of objects by an array attribute with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

The following code does NOT return the expected results of an array with 1 item.  Can someone please enlighten me about the correct syntax?

```js
let things = [{
    Name: 'Bill',
    Tags: ['tall', 'dude']
  },
  {
    Name: 'Ted',
    Tags: ['short', 'dude']
  }
];

let selectedTags = ['short', 'chick'];

let filtered = things.filter((thing => thing.Tags.indexOf(selectedTags) >= 0));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: You want to filter if Tags contain any or every selectedTag?

Comment: `selectedTags` is an array, too, but your filter function doesn't address that.

Comment: `thing.Tags.indexOf(selectedTags) >= 0` is the same as `things.Tags.indexOf("short,chick") >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Array `selectedTags` to `includes`. You need to check loop through `selectedTags` and check if tag is present in `.Tags` of object.

```js
let things = [{Name: 'Bill', Tags: ['tall','dude']},
              {Name: 'Ted', Tags: ['short','dude']}];
console.log(things);

let selectedTags = ['short','chick'];

let filtered = things.filter(x => {
  for(let tag of selectedTags){
    if(x.Tags.includes(tag)) return true;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedTags` is an array.

`.indexOf()` is wainting for a string.

You can get the string into your array by selected with index, like :

```
thing.Tags.indexOf(selectedTags[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to filter `things` based on if any of `thing.Tags` is in `selectedTags`.

You would do something like this

```
things.filter(thing => thing.Tags.some(tag => selectedTags.includes(tag)));
```

This is, I think, the most expressive way to write it. Give me all things where some of thing.Tags are included in the selectedTags array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter the items that have some `tag` that is present on the `selectedTags` array, then you can go with this:

```js
let things = [
  {Name: 'Bill', Tags: ['tall', 'dude']},
  {Name: 'Ted', Tags: ['short', 'dude']}
];

let selectedTags = ['short', 'chick'];

let filtered = things.filter(
    thing => selectedTags.some(x => thing.Tags.includes(x))
);
    
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you need to filter the items that have all the `tags` present on the `selectedTags` array, then you can use:

```js
let things = [
  {Name: 'Bill', Tags: ['tall', 'dude']},
  {Name: 'Ted', Tags: ['short', 'dude']},
  {Name: 'Test', Tags: ['short', 'chick']}
];

let selectedTags = ['short', 'chick'];

let filtered = things.filter(
    thing => selectedTags.every(x => thing.Tags.includes(x))
);
    
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over each `things` element and analyze every item in its `Tags` attribute array:

```js
let things = [{
    Name: 'Bill',
    Tags: ['tall', 'dude']
  },
  {
    Name: 'Ted',
    Tags: ['short', 'dude']
  }
];

let selectedTags = ['short', 'chick'];
let filtered = things.filter(el => {
  //Use reduce on to get a count of how many matching tags
  return el.Tags.reduce((accum, tag) => {
    if (selectedTags.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
      accum += 1;
    }
    return accum;
  }, 0);
});

console.log(filtered);
```